# Как переделать анонимный класс в статический?

Tags: java, классы, map, static

Нужно вместо анонимного класса создать статический, опыта и понимания не хватает, для того чтобы реализовать это самому, помогите

```
private final int size;

private final Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> pastResults = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<Character, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(final Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > size;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как-то так:

```
public static class MyClass<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V>() {

    private int size;

    public void setSize(int size) { this.size = size; }

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(final Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > size;
    }
}
```